# Softkeyboard Done button causing focus to skip

Tags: android

I have a set of EditTexts in my app that the user needs to fill in. Pressing "Next" on the soft keyboard advances the focus to the next EditText and at the last one I capture the soft key Enter action to validate and submit the entered data. In case there is a validation error (e.g. an unfilled field) the relevant field (i.e. the unfilled field) requests focus whilst also showing a toast to display the error.

It works fine (focuses on the correct item) if I use a Send button which calls the same validation function, but if I hit the Enter button on the soft keyboard, the focus jumps to the EditText that caused the validation error and immediately moves to the one immediately after it.

This is the snippet that sets the listener on the last EditText.

```
lastEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                if(validateFields()){ //Validation function
                    sendPressed(); //Submit function
                }
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated..